# instances.setMetadata() - nothing changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to add startup-script for an existing machine, when I do it from Google's tester ('Try this API') it works, with the client seems like nothing's changing...
Here's the code (just an example of the request) + the response I get (which looks fine) and the machine's data after sending the request.

## My Request:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from pprint import pprint
jsonPath = "myJSON.json"

credentials = GoogleCredentials.from_stream(jsonPath)
# Define gcp service
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

#Request Body
bodyData = {"fingerprint": "***","items": [{"key": "startup-script","value": "#! /bin/bash\n\nservice start sshguard"}]}
#setMeta Data Request
instance = service.instances().setMetadata(project="<PROJECT>", zone="europe-west1-b", instance="<ID>", body=bodyData)
#Execute request
response = instance.execute()
# Get instacne details
instanceget = service.instances().get(project="<PROJECT>", zone="europe-west1-b", instance="<ID>").execute()

#Print response + New Metadata
pprint(response)
print("'New Metadata:", instanceget['metadata'])
```

## Response I Get

```
{'id': '6099825023953066427',
 'insertTime': '2020-03-16T04:47:32.880-07:00',
 'kind': 'compute#operation',
 'name': 'operation-84359252330-5a0f7626e861e-cf743913-4f05cd',
 'operationType': 'setMetadata',
 'progress': 0,
 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<Project>/zones/europe-west1-b/operations/operation-1584359252330-5a0f7626e861e-cf743913-4f05cd31',
 'startTime': '2020-03-16T04:47:32.899-07:00',
 'status': 'RUNNING',
 'targetId': '<ID>',
 'targetLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<Project>/zones/europe-west1-b/instances/<ID>',
 'user': 'pubsub-aws@<Project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
 'zone': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<Project>/zones/europe-west1-b'}
'New Metadata:  {'fingerprint': '***', 'kind': 'compute#metadata'}
```

As you can see, the startup-script never added to the Metadata... I thought maybe its something with the json format? maybe the request body needs to be encoded or something?
Will appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Gave it 'Owner' permissions and it worked.
Means that I had wrong permissions.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

It is possible the setMetadata call is failing. Look in the Cloud console logs to see what the result of the operation is.

#### Option 2

`setMetadata` does not instantly apply the change, it can take a short bit of time. Because your code immediately fetches the instance, the `setMetadata` change might apply after you have fetched it.

If your script needs to check the change has applied, it should fetch the operation object until it is no longer `RUNNING`.

Comment: Thank you David. I looked in the console and noticed that I got error code 412 for all requests...(I think I got all status codes in the past but this is the first time I get 412). Can you explain please what did I do wrong? Or optional reasons for this error code? 
Thanks again.

Comment: The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setMetadata#body.request_body.FIELDS.fingerprint) say setMetadata returns 412 if fingerprint is not set correctly.  Instead of writing the metadata body yourself, read the metadata field of `service.instances().get(...)`, modify it to add your k/v, and then call setMetadata with that. This read-modify-write flow will get the fingerprint right, and preserve any other metadata on the instance.

Comment: Thanks David. It was a permissions issue. :)